# Joomla active child menu error

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

I have a problem with my joomla site.

[image]

In my site, all the sub menus (child menus) are already open.
What should I do?

http://muhunupotha.com/rh/

Comment: without code, we won't be able to help you

Comment: http://muhunupotha.com/rh/

Comment: are you using any plugin or module to this menu?

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh - Yes. ARI Ext Menu module.
But the problem was there since i installed the template

Comment: basically there is some js error with your site ,first fix it , may it be the issue